# Why does my submit button not work in php?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've created a php script which ends with `<?php $form->end('Submit'); ?>`. But why does the button submit can't function and can't be clicked?

Someone can help me solve this problem?

```
<div class="campaigns form">
<?php $form->create('Campaign'); ?>

    </fieldset>
<?php echo $form->end('Submit'); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're never actually starting the form tag, so the submit button is not inside a form, hence not clickable. You need to `echo` this line:

```
$form->create('Campaign');    ->    echo $form->create('Campaign');
```

Comment: It's there, but not `echo'd`, hence it's not in the HTML output.